# How to achieve fixed thread pool without using ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have code block like this

```
   static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
   Runnable worker = new CsvToJavaObject(newFilePath);
   executor.execute(worker);
```

I want to limit the number of threads to n(4) and not use Executor Service.How can i do it ?

Comment: By recreating the functionality of ExecutorService yourself. Why do you want to do it?

Comment: so what you have tried until now to achieve "not use Executor Service"?

Comment: i tried using Thread.activeCount() but guess it is not correct here ,it will include other threads also.i started with using an array of threads .Starting n tasks and thereafter polling if they are alive in array loop .If then its less than n i spawn another task .but it doesnt look good

Comment: So you want to copy the code which is used in a ThreadPoolExecutor and change it.  If you want to know how a thread pool works, you should read the code for it.  Then you might find all you need is to sub-class it, or you might find you don't need to change it at all.

Comment: how did people manage this before executors were introduced in java 5 ..i am sorry i just wanted to know how could we write simple logic for managing n running threads.

Answer (score 1):

What about ThreadPoolExecutor?

```
ThreadPoolExecutor threadPool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 5, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Is "4" the count of your cores? Are you trying to limit your parallel executions to the number of cores in the system? 
If so: I would just use TPL (e.g "new Task(Action)") instead, which is already respecting your system setup.
If you want, you can even manually set the number of threads the threadpool offers, see ThreadPool.SetMinThreads, but there are only a few situations where that would make sense...

Edit: My mistake, thought it was a c# issue...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to spawn a task only as required you actually want a modified BlockingQueue.

When the thread pool has a free thread, it performs a blocking take() on the queue.  Your modified Queue could create a task on demand.